# Splitting a string into strings each time the 'supposed' data type changes and.... (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

The type of string that causes my isssue:

```
strIng=[
Note 2015 2014
2 Øvrige fmansielle omkostnjnger —54.030 —10.689
Resultat før skat 2.410.717 3.273.129
Skat af Zrets resultat —581.607 —803.639
Arets resultat 1.829.1 10 2.469.490
]
```

I want this string to be:

```
strIng=[
,Note ,2015, 2014
2, Øvrige fmansielle omkostnjnger —54.030 —10.689
,Resultat før skat, 2.410.717, 3.273.129
,Skat af Zrets resultat, —581.607, —803.639
,Arets resultat, 1.829.110, 2.469.490
]
```

The goal is to have a .txt that i can import in Excel. 
I am hoping to develop a code so that it would work for another other similarly odd inputstrings like:

```
strIngAnother=[
Note 2015 2014 2014 2015
2 Øvrige fmansielle omkostnjnger —54.030 —10.689 -11.846 -19.776
Resultat før skat 2.410.717 3.273.129 1.123.563 1.125.987
Skat af Zrets resultat —581.607 —803.639 -283.957 -933.745
Arets resultat 1.829.110 2.469.490 2.243.008 1.984.222
]
```

becomming:

```
strIngAnother=[
,Note, 2015, 2014, 2014, 2015
2, Øvrige fmansielle omkostnjnger, —54.030, —10.689, -11.846, -19.776
,Resultat før skat, 2.410.717, 3.273.129, 1.123.563, 1.125.987
,Skat af Zrets resultat, —581.607, —803.639, -283.957, -933.745
,Arets resultat, 1.829.110, 2.469.490, 2.243.008, 1.984.222
]
```

please help if solvable
BR

Comment: Not sure what the question is. Do you have a string and want it to be a list?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried? What were the results? StackOverflow members try to spread our knowledge, but we aren't a code-writing service; please reference the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and [How to write a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). That said, I can tell you the problem is solvable but I prefer to teach how to come up with a solution instead of just giving a solution. (And showing effort into creating a solution puts you on the right track)